# How to use fscanf() in C to recognize patterns that are recognized as strings?

Tags: c, string, file, formatting, scanf

I want to use fscanf to recognize the following pattern:

```
Product|10|Meter
```

One product, its quantity and its meter.

Using `fscanf()` as:

```
fscanf(file, "%s|%d|%s");
```

The problem I'm having is that the the string is picking up everything, and the other variables doesn't receive any value.

This is my code:

```
while ((fscanf(arqProdTemp, "%s|%d|%s", insumo, qtdInsumos, unidade)) != EOF) {
    printf("%s - %d %s", insumo, qtdInsumos, unidade);
}
```

When I use the `printf()` function, the result of `insumo` is the entirely string!

Comment: `%s` picks up all consecutive non-whitespace characters.  Look into `%[]`, eg. `%[^|]`

Comment: But I'm going to use that instead? I need of the three values.

Comment: He's suggesting you use `"%[^|]|%d|%s"`.  That is, replace your first `%s` with `%[^|]`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could start with `fgets` and something like `strtok` for this kind of task, rather than `fscanf`.

Comment: Yeah. But until now i couldn't make what i want.

Comment: @Dmitri: You should write that as answer.

Comment: Note that you should be using `while (fscanf(…) == 3)` to ensure you read 3 values.  If you get 2, 1 or 0, you've got various format problems (it's improbable that your current pattern would return 0, but in general, that's an option).  As well as EOF indicating there is no more data to read.

Comment: Thanks Steve Summit . I used the function strtok() and i could make things works. Unfortunately, i'm having problems when passing values to a Linked List. I use the function strcpy() to pick the string values, but when i'm trying to show the list, i have a segmentation fault. One more thing: I setted values of both strings with the same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you could do

```
fscanf(arqProdTemp, "%[^|]|%d|%s", insumo, &qtdInsumos, unidade);
```

Note that if `qtdInsumos` is an integer variable you need to pass its address to `fscanf()` with `&qtdInsumos`. Not its value.

`insumo` and `unidade` are character arrays used to store the strings. Make sure that the arrays are large enough to store the strings and use width specifiers like

```
fscanf(arqProdTemp, "%14[^|]|%d|14%s", insumo, &qtdInsumos, unidade);
```

where 15 is assumed to be the size of both arrays. Change it as per your need.

Also, check the return value of `fscanf()` to see if all went well. `fscanf()` returns the number of successful assignments which in this case must be 3.

```
if( fscanf(arqProdTemp, "%[^|]|%d|%s", insumo, &qtdInsumos, unidade) != 3 )    
{
    //Something went wrong
}
```